# geom_rect doesn't behave as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay some rectangle on top of a graph. By using `geom_polygon`, it works fine.

```
dpol=data.frame(x=c(3.5,4.5,4.5,3.5, 5.5,6.5,6.5,5.5), 
                y=c(20,20,35,35,  16,16,23,23), 
                grp=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a',  'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), 
                r=c(1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8))
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_polygon(data=dpol, 
               aes(x=x, y=y, group=grp,col=grp), 
               size=1, fill=NA)
```

[image]

But when I try to use `geom_rect`, it gives errors:

```
drect=data.frame(x1=c(3.5,5.5,7.5,3,5), 
                 x2=c(4.5,6.5,8.5,7,9), 
                 y1=c(20,16,10,15,8), 
                 y2=c(35,23,20,37,25), 
                 grp=c('a','a','a','b','b'), 
                 r=c(1,2,3,4,5))
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_rect(data = drect, 
            aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2, col=grp),
            size=2, fill=NA)
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found

I noticed that `aes` takes different parameters in the two functions. Can anyone clarify what's going on?

Comment: `geom_rect()` is looking for the global `x` variable (`cyl`), which is not in `drect`.  You can use `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_rect()` to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. That solved the problem.